# C# can't receive mails on VPS

Tags: c#, email, gmail, pop3

I use [popclient](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125689/PopClient-A-POP-companion-to-SmtpClient) to receive messages from my gmail, it's works on my PC but on VPS not, i have no clue what is going on. I used gmail's specific password and i tried to change port.

Output:

```
<< +OK Gpop ready for requests from 'IP1' f15mb392228917lds

>> USER 'GMAIL ADRESS'

<< +OK send PASS

>> PASS ********

<< +OK Welcome.

>> STAT

<< +OK 14 3002232

Event Fired: QueryPopInfoCompleted
Count: 14, Total Size: 3002232 bytes
>> LIST 1

<< +OK 1 1853

>> UIDL 1

<< +OK 1 GmailId15081a8efb4c1eba

>> RETR 1

<< +OK message follows
Delivered-To: 'GMAIL ADRESS'
Received: by 'IP2' with SMTP id g1csp520741wjl;
        Mon, 19 Oct 2015 12:52:23 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 'IP3'
Event Fired: MailPopCompleted
MailPopCompletedEventArgs.Aborted : True
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Add a `try-catch` and check the `Exception.InnerException` to see a more useful error message. The current error message doesn't tell anything except "there was an exception".

Comment: OK, now there is only "ole32.dll"

Answer (score 0):

```
System.DllNotFoundException: ole32.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.__ComObject:CoCreateInstance (System.Guid,intptr,uint,System.Guid,intptr&)
  at System.__ComObject.Initialize (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.__ComObject:Initialize (System.Type)
  at Mono.Interop.ComInteropProxy.CreateProxy (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.CreateClientProxyForComInterop (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateProxyForType (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```